# Call a PHP function in Twig with context variable as an argument if the function has another argument

Tags: php, twig

In PHP I have:

```
protected function registerTwigFunctions()
{
    return [
        'count_VKcomments' => 'countVKCommentsFunction'
    ];
}

public function countVKCommentsFunction($context, $pdo) {
    $url = $context['url'];
    $sql = "SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM level_1 WHERE url = ?";
    $count = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$url])->fetchColumn();
    return $count;
}
```

In Twig I have:

```
{% set url = global.request.uri %}
{{ count_VKcomments({ 'url': url }) }
```

But it only works if I remove the `$pdo` argument from `countVKCommentsFunction`, otherwise some temporary file complains about too few arguments being passed from Twig. But I need to include that `$pdo` argument just to avoid duplicating connection to the database, which is already defined as `$pdo` in another function. At the same time, I don't understand how to properly call `countVKCommentsFunction` provided that it needs `$pdo` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

From perspective of Twig your function should only accept/care about what template practically needs to pass to it.

From perspective of PHP implementation your function needs access to state of your application (your database connection in this case).

The solution here is to decouple the two tasks:

1. Make and instantiate object that has access to the necessary state.
2. Use the object's method as callback for Twig function.

That way template data comes through arguments and state data comes through implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's completely vague. I'm asking such questions for the very reason that I'm new to all of this and can't just imagine the code I need to write from reading this kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a separate function that defines `$pdo`:

```
private function pdo() {
    $core = Core::getInstance();
    $pdo = $core->dbh;
    return $pdo;
}
```

Then in every function that needs to use this variable I added `$pdo = $this->pdo();`

Another approach would be to declare the variable as a class member, but I ended up doing it like I described.

Comment: Why don't you make a function `getPdo()` inside core? This way you wouldn't need to reference the variable everytime? You just could do `$stmt = Core::getInstance()->getPdo()->prepare($sql);`

Comment: You're right, but I don't see a big difference between referencing the variable everytime and adding `Core::getInstance()->getPdo()` to the statement everytime.

Comment: It saves you a function and an extra line each time you want to use it.. But i'm guessing that is just preference